# Forward declare std::size_t in a header

Tags: c++

After some research I have discovered that I should try to avoid `#include`ing things in my header file if a forward-declare will do. How can I forward declare `std::size_t`? Or must I also `#include <cstddef>` in my header file?

File ***my_string.h***:

```
#ifndef MY_STRING_H_
#define MY_STRING_H_

extern std::size_t;

namespace my
{
        class string
        {
        public:
                std::size_t length() const { return len; }
                const char *c_str() const;
        private:
                std::size_t len;
        }
}

#endif
```

File ***my_string.cpp***:

```
#include "my_string.h"

#include <cstddef>

const char *my::string::c_str() const
{
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
                ;       // do stuff ...

        return something;
}
```

Obviously these examples aren't complete...

I'm getting error: `error: 'size_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type` (from `my_string.h`).

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers. I figured I was wasting time trying to force not including this header, but I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extern` is for functions and variables, not for type aliases. Type aliases are defined with `typedef`s.

If you wanted to do this for one of your own types, you could copy its typedef from the header, and avoid header inclusion, but even then you would get duplicate code that is a maintenance liability.

Matters are even worse with `size_t`: since the built-in type behind it is system-dependent, you would have to reproduce the same logic or risk incompatibility. Both options are pretty bad, compared to simply including the header.

Comment: `using my_size_t = decltype(sizeof(1));` is portable ;) No header needed.

Comment: @MSalters This hack is simply brilliant! :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Note `decltype` specifier is C++11.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid include header file in a header file if you are developing a library, but you always need to include required header in cpp files.
thus it is a good practice to include specific headers only in cpp file and use forward declaration in header file.
but if you have a dependency in system header like your case then you should include that system header in your header file.

**The tip** is that by including the header in 
source files
(*.cpp , *.c) we are preventing the end user to resolve the linker dependency of the library that we have developed.

Comment: also extern is not works with type. extern will tell the compiler that the memory corresponding to given variable or function is not belongs to local module thus should be resolved at linking time.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is a typedef, you cant use it with extern - extern is used with variables or functions.

It would suffice if you make sure that before every:

```
#include "my_string.h"
```

there is

```
#include <cstddef>
```

its good practice to always include first compiler headers (the onces with < >), and then local headers (the includes with " ").

If you need a type definition as std::size_t then include it, even in header file. All headers should have proper include guards to prevent multiple definitions. Keeping to a habit of only including headers in your .cpp files is really hard. Compilers are good at optimizing multiple header includes, Visual Studio offers precompiled headers, also `#pragma once`.

Comment: I have read from multiple locations (including Google's coding guide) to include the associated header, THEN system/library headers, then all other local "" headers. I think it has to do with the fact that missing includes (I believe in my class's header) will not go unnoticed this way. I don't think ensuring `cstddef` is included before `my_string.h` because of the fact that the header is referencing `std::size_t` (for `len` and `length()`).

Comment: @RastaJedi thanks, thats interesting, here is a link for reference: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes

Comment: Of course :) and thanks for the reference link, I should have thought of that :p. Note that I don't follow their guide for includes exactly, I think the major difference being that I put C++ headers *before* C headers, and they do the opposite. But I think the rest is the same way they do it. I still haven't decided if within those groups I should use alphabetical order or just the order in which I add them to the file (i.e., for C, I usually have `stdio.h` *then* `stdlib.h` (not because it's alphabetical though. I still haven't decided what to do 100% yet).

Comment: If you use Visual Studio precompiled files, then you will have to always include precompiled header before any other. So it changes lots of things. To use precompiled headers optimally, you would put in there all the system headers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't require headers to be included in a specific order. It is a complete developmental nightmare and might require ages for people getting into the code to get to grips with. It is far better to ensure the headers are "self-contained" in terms of declarations.

This requires any dependencies in the header to be either included or better: forward declared, so that all declarations can be completed without anything missing.

If you use forward declarations, the CPP-files will still need to include extra headers to fully define the data types used, but the order should not be made important.

In the original question, my_string.h uses size_t as a member variable and as such it has to be defined and I'd much rather include the cstddef or stddef.h required, rather than expect the users of my_string.h to include it first. There is no added benefit to require one of these headers to be included before any include of my_string.h since the same amount of includes will be done.

Finally, since size_t is a typedef, it is technically possible to just typedef it yourself in the my_string.h header since multiple identical typedefs is ok in C++. However, I'd recommend against it, since the size of size_t is platform dependent.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't want to do that. The order I include in helps me to ensure I'm _not_ doing exactly that. I wouldn't have left it out if forward-declaring wasn't an option--I for sure would just `#include` it. Libraries should be self-contained. –